# Two functions, but only the first function displaying the output

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference

I tested both functions individually and they both work just fine. 
The first function suppose to display the students information, and the second functions should calculate and display the average in letter grade. Both work fine individually, but when together, which ever function come first seem to work and the second function is ignore or something.

If possible I wanted to pass the students informations into the other function, so that I wouldn't have to reopen the file again in that function. But I can't seem to be able to find anything relate to that anywhere, some tips or advices would be great.

```
void readFile(ifstream &file) {
    string names[20];

    int grade[20];

    string courses[20];
    string courses2[20];
    string courses3[20];
    string courses4[20];

    int exam1[20];
    int exam2[20];
    int exam3[20];

    int exam12[20];
    int exam22[20];
    int exam32[20];

    int exam13[20];
    int exam23[20];
    int exam33[20];

    int exam14[20];
    int exam24[20];
    int exam34[20];
    int i = 0;

    while (file >> names[i] >> grade[i]>> exam1[i] >> exam2[i] >> exam3[i] >> courses[i]>> exam12[i] >> exam22[i] >> exam32[i] >> courses2[i] >> exam13[i] >> exam23[i] >> exam33[i] >> courses3[i]>> exam14[i] >> exam24[i] >> exam34[i] >> courses4[i]) {

        cout << names[i] << "   " << exam1[i] << "   " << exam2[i] << "   " << exam3[i] << "   " << courses[i] << "  " << exam12[i] << "   " << exam22[i] << "   " << exam32[i] << "   " << courses2[i] << "  " << exam13[i] << "   " << exam23[i] << "   " << exam33[i] << "   " << courses3[i] << "  " << exam14[i] << "   " << exam24[i] << "   " << exam34[i] << "   " << courses4[i] << endl;
    }

}

void calAver(ifstream &file){

    string names[20];
    string courses[20];
    string courses2[20];
    string courses3[20];
    string courses4[20];
    int i = 0;
    int gradee[20];

    int exam1[20];
    int exam2[20];
    int exam3[20];

    int exam12[20];
    int exam22[20];
    int exam32[20];

    int exam13[20];
    int exam23[20];
    int exam33[20];

    int exam14[20];
    int exam24[20];
    int exam34[20];

    int sumC1[20];
    int sumC2[20];
    int sumC3[20];
    int sumC4[20];


    int grade[20];
    int grade1[20];
    int grade2[20];
    int grade3[20];

    string grades[20];
    string grades1[20];
    string grades2[20];
    string grades3[20];

    while (file >> names[i] >> gradee[i] >> exam1[i] >> exam2[i] >> exam3[i] >> courses[i] >> exam12[i] >> exam22[i] >> exam32[i] >> courses2[i] >> exam13[i] >> exam23[i] >> exam33[i] >> courses3[i] >> exam14[i] >> exam24[i] >> exam34[i] >> courses4[i]) {

        sumC1[i] = exam1[i] + exam2[i] + exam3[i];
        grade[i] = sumC1[i] / 3;
        if (grade[i] >= 90) {
            grades[i] = 'A';
        }
        else if (grade[i] < 90 && grade[i] >= 80) {
            grades[i] = 'B';
        }
        else if (grade[i] < 80 && grade[i] >= 70) {
            grades[i] = 'C';
        }
        else if (grade[i] < 70 && grade[i] >= 60) {
            grades[i] = 'D';
        }
        else if (grade[i] < 60) {
            grades[i] = 'F';
        }       

        sumC2[i] = exam12[i] + exam22[i] + exam32[i];
        grade1[i] = sumC2[i] / 3;
        if (grade1[i] >= 90) {
            grades1[i] = 'A';
        }
        else if (grade1[i] < 90 && grade1[i] >= 80) {
            grades1[i] = 'B';
        }
        else if (grade1[i] < 80 && grade1[i] >= 70) {
            grades1[i] = 'C';
        }
        else if (grade1[i] < 70 && grade1[i] >= 60) {
            grades1[i] = 'D';
        }
        else if (grade1[i] < 60) {
            grades1[i] = 'F';
        }

        sumC3[i] = exam13[i] + exam23[i] + exam33[i];
        grade2[i] = sumC3[i] / 3;
        if (grade[i] >= 90) {
            grades2[i] = 'A';
        }
        else if (grade2[i] < 90 && grade2[i] >= 80) {
            grades2[i] = 'B';
        }
        else if (grade2[i] < 80 && grade2[i] >= 70) {
            grades2[i] = 'C';
        }
        else if (grade2[i] < 70 && grade2[i] >= 60) {
            grades2[i] = 'D';
        }
        else if (grade2[i] < 60) {
            grades2[i] = 'F';
        }

        sumC4[i] = exam14[i] + exam24[i] + exam34[i];
        grade3[i] = sumC4[i] / 3;
        if (grade3[i] >= 90) {
            grades3[i] = 'A';
        }
        else if (grade3[i] < 90 && grade3[i] >= 80) {
            grades3[i] = 'B';
        }
        else if (grade3[i] < 80 && grade3[i] >= 70) {
            grades3[i] = 'C';
        }
        else if (grade3[i] < 70 && grade3[i] >= 60) {
            grades3[i] = 'D';
        }
        else if (grade3[i] < 60) {
            grades3[i] = 'F';
        }

        cout << grades[i] << " "<< grades1[i] << " "<< grades2[i] << " "<< grades3[i] << endl;

    }

}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    ifstream files;
    files.open("StudentGrade.txt");

    if (files.fail()) {
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
    }
    else

            cout << " Students: " << endl;
            readFile(files);
            cout << "Average: " << endl;
            calAver(files);

        /*while (!files.eof()) {
            cout << calAver(files) << endl;
        }*/
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: You need to reset the stream between calls. `readFile` reads the entire file, so when `calAver` starts, there's nothing left to read. Possibly `files.seekg (0, files.beg);` See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/

Comment: Yeah, I just see that I forgot to close the file, but it still doesn't work. The same thing.

Comment: I didn't say anything about closing the file. You need to `seek` back to the start of the file before attempting to read it again.

Comment: What is the point of all those arrays in `readFile` if you only use the first index anyway? Actually, this applies to both functions, you never increment `i` anywhere.